# Prevent ads from launching apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I use a lot of free apps, and understand that ads are an essential part of making sure the maker gets paid. However, I am finding more and more ads that will **automatically** open the App Store or a web site in my browser, as I'm in the middle of doing something.

I can understand that it's likely not the app-makers choosing the ads, and that the ads are based on some special code the company gives them. I'm not against blocking all ads, but I do not wish to root my phone. *All I want is to block apps from automatically reloading URLs, causing other applications to launch and take focus on my phone*. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to root your device and install [**Adfree**.](http://adfree.bigtincan.com/) This small app will block all the ads on your device.

NOTE : I am also not against devs for adding ads to their apps, but intense ads popups are irritating.

Comment: Any non-root methods available?

Comment: I guess not... The idea is to edit the 'hosts' file, which can only be done if you have root access.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a message to the appstore you downloaded your app from. What the developer or the ad provider the app used is doing is against the rules of reputable app stores. Personally I would never allow an ad to take a user away from my application unless the ad was legitimately clicked on. Also, do not put too much faith in the adblockers as many android developers know how to easily block all adblockers on rooted or unrooted phones.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/) which doesn't requires the phone to be rooted. It also respects your view:

> I use a lot of free apps, and understand that ads are an essential part of making sure the maker gets paid.

You can opt-in for this:

> #### What are Acceptable Ads?
>
> Many people use Adblock Plus to block annoying ads. However, we don't think that all ads are bad, and we are fully aware that they finance many websites. Therefore we have established strict criteria to identify Acceptable Ads: unobtrusive ones that don't need to be blocked. Websites that are willing to comply with these criteria can apply to have their ads added to the Acceptable Ads exception list, which will unblock them for all users that decided to keep Acceptable Ads enabled. Note that if you don't want to see any ads, you will always be able to opt out of this.
>
> Please see the Acceptable Ads FAQ to learn more. ([Source](https://adblockplus.org/en/about))

---

#### What is Adblock Plus?

> Adblock Plus lets you block annoying ads, tracking, malware and other things you may not want in your browser. Adblock Plus is an open source project created by Wladimir Palant in 2006. Eyeo was founded in 2011 by Wladimir Palant and Till Faida to make its development sustainable. [[More Info](https://adblockplus.org/en/about)]

**Note**: When I used this app a year ago, it had problem with blocking ads on Mobile Data and worked only on Wifi. Please update this answer if it works with Mobile Data now. Also, once installed, disabling it and trying to use browser resulted in no internet connection in any web browser. It is possible that these issues may have been get ridden of by the subsequent updates.

Comment: You are correct, it only works on Wifi. I'll test this out for a few days, then come back to let you know my findings. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work :-(thanks though

Comment: @CanadianLuke I found some solutions other than what I already mentioned. Ended up with this guide. The solutions proposed uses changes in DNS settings and adding dedicated Ad-blocking DNS servers like of **Fool DNS**, **Ad Barricade**. You can look on Google for how to change DNS settings in Android if you're unaware of, or there are some apps that can change DNS for you in Play Store. http://7labs.heypub.com/mobile/ad-blocker-android-ios.html

Comment: @CanadianLuke Did you try this DNS technique?

Comment: Lord they still only work on WiFi

Comment: @CanadianLuke There is this app named [Block it!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.resolution.blockit) which claims to use some VPNservice API for blocking ads. People reported good reviews. This should be working easily with Mobile Data. On the other hand, I found this [Ad block or Stop this blurb](http://www.1mobile.com/ad-block-or-stop-this-blurb-2267878.html) which promises high but seems shady to me.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Sorry for multiple pings here, but any luck with the ad blocking?

Comment: Slowly training block it. It's very inconvenient though, and it doesn't seem to add lists very well